# TextWatcher set min and max values

Tags: android, kotlin, textwatcher

im trying to make an imput to be limited to a range of numbers using the `TextWatcher` and force the min and max if user try to go out of range. Works almost as expected but on a delete, allowing a visually empty text. How can i avoid that?

```
inputVal.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s:Editable) {     //s=""
            var curVal = s.toString().toIntOrNull()?:5  //curVal=5
            if (curVal <  5){
                curVal = 5
                s.replace(0,s.length,"5")  <- problem here, not replacing cuz s.length=0
            }else if (curVal >50){
                curVal = 50
                s.replace(0,s.length,"50")
            }

            //some other things to do based on 'curVal'
        }})
```

**update** what i need is, for example, u have a '20' and adds a 0 (will be 200) transform it to a '50'; and if delete a 0 (being 2) force a 5 in the input.

Comment: Is anything wrong with this approach
[Input Filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter) ?

Comment: @pintu236 I need to change the text if the value is out of range (put a 5 if its under, or 50 if upper) and in the InputFilters doc say `Also beware that you should not attempt to make any changes to dest from this method; you may only examine it for context.`

Comment: If you check their LengthFilter class to limit input to max value, you can see they are using `dest` to get current entered string information. You write some logic to limit within min and max value. The text watcher approach can certainly turn into ANR if you don't have proper exit condition because it will call again when you are trying to manipulate editable.

Comment: `InputFilter` its to allow or prevent the new incoming text, but not for edit the actual Inputs text itself. OR i cant figure it out, if u can provide an example will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after testing i could make it work, here is the code:

```
class NumberWatcher(private val mMin: Int, private val mMax: Int)
:TextWatcher{
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    override fun afterTextChanged(s:Editable) {
        Log.d("TextWatcher","Triggered '$s'")
        if (s.isEmpty() || s.toString().toInt() < mMin){
            s.replace(0, s.length, mMin.toString())
            return //will retrigger after the change, to avoid double excecution
        }else if (s.toString().toInt() > mMax){
            s.replace(0, s.length, mMax.toString())
            return //will retrigger after the change, to avoid double excecution
        }

        Log.d("TextWatcher","Do some things with '$s'")
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

usage:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(NumberWatcher(5,50))
```

The log:

```
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '45'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '45'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '4'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '5'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '5'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '95'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '50'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '50'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '0'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '5'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '5'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '35'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '35'
D/TextWatcher: Triggered ''
D/TextWatcher: Triggered '5'
D/TextWatcher: Do some things with '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If **s** will be empty, the curVal will be 5.

So it won't trigger any of the conditions.

Maybe try with:

```
if (curVal <=  5)
```

Comment: its ok, it needs to trigger when input is under 5, for example if user put a 3 it force a 5, or if put a 90 force a 50. The problem is, let say, u have a 9 and DELETE, fist if triggers and `curVal` is set to 5 but `s.replace(0,s.length,"5")` becomes a `s.replace(0,0,"5")` so no text is changed and the input stays empty

Answer (score 0):

You can change as per your preference; we only need to use source and dest only.

source returns the new input entered in edittext or empty if pressed backspace
dest returns prev input which in buffer already

Let's say if I enter 6 first time in edittext source returns 6 and dest returns empty as no input in buffer for first time,
if enter 7 next then source will return 7 but dest will return 6. Using this we can check the limit.

```
class InputRangeFilter(val mMin: Int, val mMax: Int) : InputFilter {

        override fun filter(
            source: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            dest: Spanned?,
            dstart: Int,
            dend: Int
        ): CharSequence? {


            val finalValue = (dest.toString().trim() + source.toString().trim()).toInt()
            
            return if (source?.isEmpty() == true && dest?.isEmpty() == true) {
                ""
            } else if (finalValue in (mMin + 1) until mMax) {
                null // keep original
            } else {
                if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(source) && source.toString().trim().toInt() < mMin)
                    && finalValue < mMax
                ) {
                    if (source.toString().toInt() == 0) {
                        ""
                    } else {
                        source
                    }
                } else {
                    ""
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**Usage:**

```
binding.edtText.filters = arrayOf(InputRangeFilter(5, 100))
```

Comment: what i need is, for example, u have a '20' and adds a 0 (will be 200) transform it to a '100'; and if delete a 0 (being 2) force a 5 in the input. Filter is to prevent add that extra 0 if the value is more than the upper limit.